# How to set a line of code to a variable

Tags: c#

I have a line of code:

```
GameObject.Find("colorswitchred (" + id.ToString() + ")").transform.GetComponent<Main>().state
```

this line gets used several times throughout the code.  I was wondering if there was a way to get it so I could just have a variable like s to represent this line of code so every time i want to say GameObject.Find("colorswitchred (" + id.ToString() + ")").transform.GetComponent().state = 0, i can just put s = 0

Comment: You don't put code in variables, it's a function you want

Comment: Sometimes called "method"

Comment: Yes, <ObjectType> gameState = GameObject.Find("colorswitchred (" + id.ToString() + ")").transform.GetComponent<Main>().state

Comment: Although pointers to methods exist (so-called delegates), you should try the easy way: add a method to your class that executes thise code. You should definitly have a look into basic programming-principles, in particular on OOP.

Answer (score 6):

Simply stick it in a method with a useful name:

```
public void SetColorSwitchRedState(int id, int newState)
{
    GameObject.Find("colorswitchred (" + id.ToString() + ")").transform.GetComponent<Main>().state = newState;
}
```

Then you can call that:

```
SetColorSwitchRedState(42, 0);
```

Comment: Useful name! Yes! That!

Answer (score 3):

> ...i can just put s = 0

No, but you can get close

```
s(id, 0);
```

You could do this by declaring a delegate:

```
Action<int, int> s = (id, newState) => GameObject.Find("colorswitchred (" + id.ToString() + ")").transform.GetComponent<Main>().state = newState;
```

A delegate is a pointer to a method, in this instance it's expecting an int (`id`) and another int (the value you want to set).

It should be stated though that `s` isn't a very meaningful name, and methods should have meaningful names. This answer is NOT the right way to do it, but it literally answers your question.

Comment: While technically correct, I doubt OP understands what this does. OP does not even know what a method is. Why would he understand lambdas?

Comment: @ThomasWeller While *you're* technically correct, I'm just answering the question posed. If this leads the OP to have another question, so be it.

Comment: @Jamiec That's not very helpful.

Comment: QA format means the question/answer will be read by users with different programming skill levels. "Too complicated" shouldn't be the reason for downvoting.

Comment: And @SimonForsberg I'm not sure what you havent found helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a property.

```
public int S
{ 
      get {return GameObject.Find("colorswitchred (" + id.ToString() + ")").transform.GetComponent<Main>().state;}
      set 
      {
       GameObject.Find("colorswitchred (" + id.ToString() + ")").transform.GetComponent<Main>().state = value;

      }
```

}

Comment: OP wants to put an argument to the pointer which you can´t with your code.

Comment: Yep, true. He should use a method. Or else he could set a class variable id  first and then set the value with S = 0. Many ways to do it really